# GD imagejpeg() compression?

Tags: php, compression, gd, steganography

I'm working on a project where I edit the pixels of a jpg in PHP using the GD library.
Its **very crucial** and key to my project that the output from PHP **retains the pixel values** I set (cough-steganography-cough).

This is the first time I've attempted image manipulation in PHP. I've had no problems before in my Java implementations, so I was foolish not to investigate GD's `jpeg` compression quality before pursuing further.

It turns out that after all my effort, my code does not function the way its supposed to. I am pretty sure it is not my code (tested the encode and decode functions on edited image resources and they worked).

**My questions are:**

1. The only problem I can see is with `imagejpeg()`'s compression. Could I be right?
2. Are there any libraries that provide the compression that I need?(retain pixel values that I changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *JPEG* file format is not very suitable for steganography if you do the [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) pixel by pixel.

*JPEG* uses an image compression - that even with maximum quality - that will destroy the information on the bit level on each pixel. The jpeg type of compression (**[lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression)**) is made for the human eye/brain to retain the image but not the bits of the image in the file .

You need to use an image format that is capable to retain the pixels - as you wrote it already as well. Such a format more likely is *BMP* with *RLE* compression or the *TIFF* image format with *ZIP* or *RLE* compression. That's called **[lossless data compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression)**.

Comment: I think I'll try PNG or GIF, both supported by GD. Thanks for the info. Will post results later!

Comment: ...And PNG works great! Thanks for the heads up on compression types vs. file types, I neglected to take that into account.

Answer (score 3):

By default the quality of the image output from `imagejpeg` is 75, Try setting it at 100 to get the image at full quality.

```
  bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) for further details.

Also try using [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php). (I think you would have been using `imagecopyresized` somewhere in your code. Use `imagecopyresampled` instead of it. )

**EDIT**

Then I think you should try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)(or GD2). It gives a better quality than GD . Check [this](http://qdig.sourceforge.net/Main/ImageMagickVersusGD)

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention I did set the quality to 100, no luck there.
Also I don't use imagecopyresized in my code :/

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately I think I'm using GD2. I'll give ImageMagick a shot but my current web host doesn't support it/allow me to install. -sigh- Yet another problem added to my plate

Comment: Think this is all that PHP could offer you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `imagepng()` instead of the `imagejpeg()` function and set the compression to 0 :

`bool imagepng ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality [, int $filters ]]] )`

See : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php